# My sql query sum of highest points for each category

Tags: mysql, sum

upload table

```
id   category_id    
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       1
```

In Ratings Table

```
id     upload_id    points
1       1             5
2       2             3
3       3             2
4       4             2
5       1             5
```

I want to display  all the records from ratings table except id 4 because id 4 is the same category id 1

I excepted result

Uploaded_id 1 has sum of 10 points

Uploaded_id 2 has sum of 3 points

Uploaded_id 3 has sum of 2 points

Please help me.

Thanks In advance

Sasikumar

Comment: And what have you tried, and why not show 4 *instead of* 1? (Yes I know I'm supposed to flag/vote to close the question, but let's give it a chance)

Comment: Where a category has multiple uploads, how do you decide for which upload you want to sum ratings?  That is, in your example above, for category 1 (which, as you point out, has both uploads 1 and 4) why not include upload 4 and exclude upload 1?

Comment: @Strawberry In more than half of SQL questions I've seen the OP hasn't tried anything, so these days I just vote (unless it's something that looks non-basic, in which case I often answer it, if able).

Answer (score 0):

```
select upload_id, sum(points) 
from rating r, 
(select min(id) id from upload group by category_id) a 
where a.id = r.upload_id group by upload_id
```

Comment: Yes - assuming that, for each category, the OP always wants to select the upload with the minimal `id`.

Comment: Yes, Thats the assumption i am gone with.